# Pandas/Python - update dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df:

          Wins     Ratio
id
234         10      None
143         32      None
678          2      None
```

I'm running a model to find out Ratio for each id.
My model is finding Ratio, it is in another data frame, that looks like this:

```
result:

143
Wins     32
Ratio   987
```

However, I'm struggling to update `df` with ratio. I'm looking for a function that simply updates df for the id `143`. Tryed to use the pd.dataframe.update() but seems it doesn't work that way (or I was unable to make it work). Can someone help on that?

Comment: what is B? in the question

Comment: I'm very confused by this question

Comment: I'm very sorry guys, I changed the dataframes but forgot to change the text. Now it is alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where:

```
df
```

Outputs:

```
     Wins Ratio
id             
234    10  None
143    32  None
678     2  None
```

And:

```
result
```

Outputs:

```
       143
Wins    32
Ratio   98
```

You can update df using `combine_first`:

```
df.replace('None',np.nan).combine_first(result.T)
```

Output:

```
     Wins  Ratio
143    32   98.0
234    10    NaN
678     2    NaN
```

Comment: I was able to do it using <code>results=pd.DataFrame(results).T</code> and <code>df=df.combine_first(results)</code>. Thanks for the combine_first tip